# Custom metadata fields in Windows file manager (or other software)

Tags: file-management, metadata, sorting

I'm trying to organize a collection of maybe 500 or so journal articles, stored in a combination of .pdf and .djvu formats.  I'd like to be able to sort the collection by author(s), title, journal name, year, and subject keywords.  Is there a way to create metadata fields for this information in the Windows file system (similar to how .mp3 files come with tags for album, title, track length, etc)?  Or, if not, is there some software (preferably free) that can do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books, which supports pdf and jvu among many other formats and includes a viewer for most e-book formats, but also much more:

- Library Management
- E-book conversion
- Syncing to e-book reader devices
- Downloading news from the web and converting it into e-book form
- Comprehensive e-book viewer
- Content server for online access to your book collection

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two other options : [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org) and [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com). Both are made for academic papers and citations.